# Prevent tibble from abbreviating column names

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

When using tibble 1.4.1, a tibble printed on the console will often abbreviate column names.

For example, set your console width to about 400 px  wide and print the dplyr::starwars data frame. Column names are shown as:

```
name     height  mass hair_c~ skin_c~ eye_c~ birth_~ gender home~ spec~ films vehi~ star~
```

I tried setting `options(tibble.width = 6)`, thinking that would only print 6 columns, but it still prints all columns.

Is there a way to prevent tibble from abbreviating column names and return to the previous behavior where it only printed the columns it had room for?

Comment: Looks like that was [fixed in version 1.4.2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/news.html).

Comment: It is indeed. Thank goodness--I was seriously ready to pitch tibble out the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a couple problems going on here. In version 1.4.1, `tibble` moved to using the [`pillar` package](http://pillar.r-lib.org/index.html) for print formatting--the defaults options for `pillar` weren't optimal. Too, there was a bug that kept `options(tibble.width = 6)` from working.

Upgrading tibble to 1.4.2, as MrFlick recommends, changes the `pillar` defaults to much more reasonable options and solves the `tibble.width` bug as well.

Changing the exposed [options for `pillar`](http://pillar.r-lib.org/reference/pillar-package.html#package-options) might also help tibble print formatting on your console, depending on what font you're using.